# Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, shell: Grep not work immediately

Tags: microsoft-windows, shell, android

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1.

I has Android application. And in console I start Android command "**adb logcat"** to show logs from Android device.
But it's show many text. And I want to filter to show only lines that I need.

So. I want in console to show only lines that content text "**com.android.testproject"**.

First I show text without filter:

1. Emacs: run shell (*M-x shell*)
2. Run android command : **adb logcat**

Here result. Show all text (no filter)

[image]

OK!
Now I want to filter.

My steps on Windows console:

1. Open windows console: "*cmd.exe*"
2. Enter command: **adb logcat|grep com.android.testproject**
3. Result is show only lines that content text "**com.android.testproject**".

It's work. OK.

Here screenshot.
[image]

Now I want to do same (filter) on Emacs.
My steps:

1. Open shell: "*M-x shell*"
2. Enter command: **adb logcat|grep com.android.testproject**
3. But nothing happend. Why?

But if I press "*C-c C-c*" (**Break**) then in shell success show filtered text.

Question: Why Emacs not immediately  filter text?

Comment: It's probably something todo with Windows not implementing [PTY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo_terminal)s

Answer (score 1):

Can't answer you directly, however for me, using

```
GNU Emacs 25.1.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2016-09-17
```

and grep

```
c:\>grep --version
grep --version
GNU grep 2.5.4

c:\>dir | grep -i pro
dir | grep -i pro
06/08/2017  16:08    <DIR>          Program Files
24/08/2017  19:02    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
```

Seem to work okay.

Perhaps if you try with -Q flag to suppress your config and try again?

Comment: Instead of `dir`, try with a command that doesn't terminate immediately. `ping` perhaps.

Comment: I try with -Q flag, but result is the same. Not work correct. My grep version = 3.0.

Comment: Okay - I wonder then if this is your problem, see (efaq-w32) Subprocess buffering